# Updating Label before opening a new window in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFX. My program starts with a login screen. After login it opens a new window.
But before the new window starts (which takes a while) I want to set a label like "loading main program..." I have this code:

```
/* setting label */
label_LoginInfo.setText("Starte Hauptfenster...");
label_LoginInfo.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
label_LoginInfo.setVisible(true); 
oeffneHauptfenster(); //open new window
```

But the label never appears like the code isn't executed sequentially. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: There is no appreciable time between setting the text of the label and opening the new window (assuming you are not doing anything that is time-consuming in your `oeffneHauptfenster()` method; and if you are you need to move the time-consuming work to another thread). In particular, no new frame will actually be rendered to the screen between calling `label_LoginInfo.setText(...)` and opening the new window, so you'll never see the new text. It's not really clear what you're expecting this to do...

Comment: Is there any way to force the UI to render once more before oeffneHauptfenster() is called? Opening the new window takes its time (something between 3 to 10 sec), that's why I want to show that label.

Comment: No. But opening a window shouldn't take anything like that long, unless you are performing some long-running computation or other process. If so, you should do that in a background thread and open the window in the FX Application Thread when it's done. Probably you are asking the wrong question to solve whatever actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I almost figured that I should put some code in another thread. When I started that project everything was fast enough but the clients WiFi is somewhat slow. And now, everything takes ages.
I'm going to refactor the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, you should *never* download data over a network connection on the UI thread. (Unless you are trying to emulate the behavior of something like Microsoft products... ;).)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because they run on the same thread. You need to run a thread that performs the `oeffneHauptfenster` and another thread for the message. Having them both in the same thread will simply follow the logic, write the message but it never gets displayed because it loads the other window.

Comment: But open a new javaFX window in another (non-javaFX-Thread) wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: Actually, you don't open different windows. You open a window and first, in your first thread set the label and the second thread renders the window.